# MKMapView crash in ios6 at the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, mkmapview

MKMapView crash in iOS 6 for the first time when app is launched in my device. after crash it runs smoothly. It only happens on the first launch of app in any device.

Example: app launches in my iPhone 4S. Crashed.
I again tap on app and it is running smoothly.

Please help me. i am not able to debug it as it is not entering into view controller. I am using storyboard and MKMapView is there in storyboard.

Comment: please make question clear. Add an error text...

Comment: @Cemsi : It is not showing any error. I needto explicitly type "bt" and get the crash report. But thats not gonna help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add Mapkit/Mapkit.h framework to the project at buildsettings. And then import the mapkit framework to the project. set the MKmapviewDelegate at in .h file. And then Create outlet for the MKmapview. Drag and drop the Mapview to the xib file and connect the outlet to the xib mapview object.

## import

## import

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

```
IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;
```

}

Comment: *gajchtr, I appreciate your help . But i have already done that. I am using storyboard. App crashed before viewdidload.

Answer (score 3):

this issue is only storyboard related. Try resetting simulator and run again.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my late answer.may be it will helpful to someone else.

I faced the same problem. I found its solution. It is crashing only for Storyboard.

Try the following:
1. create outlet for Mapview
2. Set its delegate in viewDidLoad
3. Try loading the map with delay. (In my case it helped)
4. remove delegate on dealloc.